# How do I submit the first form on a page with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit, userscripts, tampermonkey

How do I automatically submit the first form on the page with a userscript on Tampermonkey?

For example, there are three forms/submit buttons on the page. When the userscript is loaded, it automatically submits the first form found on the page, as if pressing the submit button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same way you would from the document itself:

```
document.forms[0].submit()
```

Comment: Oh, I will try that. Thanks for the fast reply. :D